# utf8 collation difference between unicode and danish

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

Well hello there.
I'm changing the charset of a database from `latin1_sweedish_ci` to `utf8`. I've allways used `utf8_danish_ci` because it's the closest to the Norwegian character style - I think.
But what about `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Some time ago; It was preferred to use `_general_ci` for better/faster performance, and `_unicode_ci` for more accuracy because of the sorting algorithm is more complex in the latter. But since the speed/performace is no longer an issue - or not so much an issue i most cases anymore - `_unicode_ci` is ok to use in most situations?

But how does `_unicode_ci` differ from `_danish_ci`?
Is it the last three letters `æ`, `ø`, `å` in the nordic alphabet that is taken into account?

Most comparisson (one vs the other) I can find is only between `_general_ci` and `_unicode_ci`.

Anyone know of any examples for when to use `_unicode_ci` or when to use `_danish_ci` would be highly appreciated...

Comment: The language specific collations like `danish` are about the *sort order* and *comparison* that these languages prefer for certain characters. I'm totally making this up because I don't know Danish, but in say in general use "o" and "ø" are considered two different characters, while in Danish for purposes of comparison and sorting they're considered equal (think *phonebook order*). Another example would be that in German "ß" is considered equal to "ss" for this purpose. Does this answer the question?

Comment: don't know about that. Since `ø` is a common letter in the danish language I would assume that those two letters would be treated differently... In `_general_ci` on the other hand, those two letters would be treated as equal letters while in `unicode_ci` - maybe not again... But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Well, again, I'm not entirely sure what's considered equal where, I was just making it up for the sake of comparison. Does this help though? You can look up the exact rules in the documentation somewhere; or are the exact rules what you're asking for?

Comment: I was looking to see if there was any reason for me to be using `_danich_ci` instead of `_unicode_ci` or `_general_ci`.  
There is both `_swedish_ci` and `_danish_ci`, but not any `_norwegian_ci`...

Comment: @ThomasK: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet = Same.

Answer (score 7):

In short, if your app is multilingual and storing multiple languages within the same tables, you're mostly screwed and should worry about sorting/collating outside of the database -- utf8_general_ci is then as good as any other.

If it only supports a single language, you'll do fine by setting the correct collation at the db level -- in your case, utf8_danish_ci indeed, since it's the same as norwegian if wikipedia is anything to go by.

In case you'd like to read more on collation, the ICU docs has colorful examples of how thorny this kind of stuff gets. Quoting extensively:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation

> [H]ere are some of the ways languages vary in ordering strings:
>
> The letters A-Z can be sorted in a different order than in English.
>   For example, in Lithuanian, "y" is sorted between "i" and "k".
>
> Combinations of letters can be treated as if they were one letter. For
>   example, in traditional Spanish "ch" is treated as a single letter,
>   and sorted between "c" and "d".
>
> Accented letters can be treated as minor variants of the unaccented
>   letter. For example, "é" can be treated equivalent to "e".
>
> Accented letters can be treated as distinct letters. For example, "Å"
>   in Danish is treated as a separate letter that sorts just after "Z".
>
> Unaccented letters that are considered distinct in one language can be
>   indistinct in another. For example, the letters "v" and "w" are two
>   different letters according to English. However, "v" and "w" are
>   considered variant forms of the same letter in Swedish.
>
> A letter can be treated as if it were two letters. For example, in
>   traditional German "ä" is compared as if it were "ae".
>
> Thai requires that the order of certain letters be reversed.
>
> French requires that letters sorted with accents at the end of the
>   string be sorted ahead of accents in the beginning of the string. For
>   example, the word "côte" sorts before "coté" because the acute accent
>   on the final "e" is more significant than the circumflex on the "o".
>
> Sometimes lowercase letters sort before uppercase letters. The reverse
>   is required in other situations. For example, lowercase letters are
>   usually sorted before uppercase letters in English. Latvian letters
>   are the exact opposite.
>
> Even in the same language, different applications might require
>   different sorting orders. For example, in German dictionaries, "öf"
>   would come before "of". In phone books the situation is the exact
>   opposite.
>
> Sorting orders can change over time due to government regulations or
>   new characters/scripts in Unicode.

Comment: +1, good answer. Is `utf8_general_ci` (or the unicode variant) ***always*** as good as any other?

Comment: IMHO, yes. Even sophisticated software engineers don't fully appreciate the subtleties (or benefits) of sorting words in their "correct" order. Many rely on c-string sorting instead, because it's simpler. So I'd suggest that the bar is low enough that anything probably goes...

Comment: You could easily add COLLATE to each relevant query, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please bear in mind that Collation != Encoding.

Encoding is the mapping between integers (which all that a database can store at the end of the day) and human readable graphic representations of characters.

Collation is the ordering rule used to sort characters according to the conventional alphabetical order of a given language. Notice that this ordering does not reflect the actual order of the internal, numeric representation.

Your question reduces to the following: what kind of alphabetical order should you use in your application? This cannot be answered.

Comment: -1, It can be answered... Supposing the application is primarily used to store danish text, then choose `utf8_danish_ci`. *Iff* however, `utf8_unicode_ci` (perhaps [doubtfully] even `utf8_general_ci`) turns out to sort the same **danish** text in the same order (in other words, *if it **extends** the danish collation*) then use `utf8_unicode_ci` for the sake of having a more complete collation and be able to also correctly sort texts in other languages <- there.

Comment: @AlixAxel This could be true if your assumptions were true. However, I still fail to find which clue might suggest that the General collation extends the Danish one. You also seem to forget that the collation can be changed on-the-fly, depending on the need of the moment, at no cost. You should perhaps rephrase your first supposition: "Supposing the application is primarily used to *render* Danish text".

Comment: I can add; It is Norwegian text I need to store in the database, and not danish. Since there was no norwegian alternative, I've been using danish collocation. Mostly because I didn't know what unicode or general was, and because it was the closest to norwegian language.

Comment: @YaK: "Supposing the application is primarily used to render Danish text" - if not, why would the OP be considering that locale? I stand by what I said.

Comment: @ThomasK: The Wikipedia page I linked to seems to imply that both languages use the same sorting order and the same characters.

Comment: Then you are good to go with Danish collation, judging by the comments in the MySQL source code: "`static const char danish[]=  /* Also good for Norwegian */`". Remember, however, that Collation has no effect whatsoever on *storage*. Encoding has. Collation is used at rendering time.

Comment: Yes, It seems like doing what I've been doing so far is just about correct.

Comment: @ThomasK: "Remember, however, that Collation has no effect whatsoever on storage. Encoding has." - I've just learned that that's not true. Try to find `Å` in this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca397/1/0) vs in this one (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca84/1/0).

Comment: @Alix Axel This is a very interesting case where collation does have an effect on insertion, because `'A' = 'Å'` as far as utf8_unicode_* collation is concerned (resulting in a unicity constraint violation). I stand corrected, I did not think of this specific use case.

Comment: @YaK: "collation has no effect whatsoever on storage" + "collation does have an effect on insertion" = "I stand corrected". Does not compute. But whatever, I'm done arguing.

Comment: Based on the test Alix did, and what MySQL source code says - `_danish_ci` is the most correct collocation to use for my applications. I appriciate all the answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe the `utf8_danish_ci` is a subset of (either) `utf8` (collation).

That being said, and if your database is `utf8` encoded, it makes little sense to use the danish collation.

Quick test (since I'm in a hurry and I can't find a collation list for `utf8_unicode`):

- create a table with all [these chars](http://developer.mimer.com/charts/danish.htm) (both lower and uppercase) with collation `utf8_danish_ci`
- select all records, ordered by char ASC
- change the collation of the table to `utf8_general_ci` or preferably `utf8_unicode_ci`
- if the characters have the same order in both queries, chose either, doesn't make a difference

Related [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

---

#### UPDATE

My hypothesis was wrong.

I did [some](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca397/1/0) [tests](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca84/1/0) and apparently `utf8_unicode_ci` does not sort in the same order, so nevermind.

Comment: `utf8_danish_ci` is not a "subset" of `utf8`. It sounds like you're confusing *encoding* and *collation*. An encoding is a set and hence one may be a *subset* of another. Collations are simply *comparison rules*.

Comment: Since collations are only about the comparison between characters, the output of the character itself will be the same in either one of them. Meaning; When outputting text, like articles and such, it doen't really matter which one I use. But for sorting a list of whatever - it could make a difference... correct?

Comment: @deceze: What I meant to say, was that the collation `utf8_danish_ci` was a subset of `utf8_unicode_ci` and probably `utf8_general_ci` too.

Comment: @ThomasK: 100% correct: *it could*, doesn't mean *it will*. For that, you either have to get both collations character lists and see if the danish chars appear in the same order in both collations. Alternatively, you could just run the test I mentioned in my answer - you'll get the same answer.

Comment: -1 A collation is not a set, it cannot be a subset. It makes sense to use the Danish collation if you want to render Danish text (eg. a Danish dictionary).

Comment: "What I meant to say, was that the collation utf8_danish_ci was a subset of utf8_unicode_ci and probably utf8_general_ci too" -- Methinks it isn't... The collation in danish actually differs from that of german, swedish, or english for that matter. Some pointers on how messy this stuff can get: http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation

Comment: @Denis: It also differs from Latin-1/15 but I can tell you from own experience that the characters with diacritic appear in the same order in `utf8_[general/unicode]_ci`, some examples: `àáãèéìíòóõùúç`. The examples you're giving are not comparable because german, swedish and english are not super-sets (if you wanna call them that) like portuguese < utf8.

Comment: @Denis: A collation is a structure that defines the order for a set of characters, in that sense UTF-8 collations can present the danish characters in the same order that the danish collation does: [ASCII] + [Latin] + [Danish] + [...].

Answer (score -1):

Collation determines both which characters can be stored in a table, as well as the order of characters. Choosing anything starting with utf8 should cover most needs for character storage so utf8_general_ci is a good choice. If you're going to focus on one language, you can choose the local collation, such as utf8_danish_ci which means the order will be be Danish characters and case insensitive (the ci part).

For a multilingual application, you can store fields with utf8_general_ci and when you're in need of a specific sort or comparison to match your preferred language, add the COLLATE word to your query with your preferred collation from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

The answer provided by @Denis above, claiming you cannot sort in MySQL, is wrong in my experience.

Comment: You're not answering the question though. OP is asking how one collation might differ from another, and to the best of my knowledge I answered as honestly as I could: collations differ. What is your point in down voting an (honest) answer that highlights how it's different?

Comment: I down voted your answer due to your first paragraph which I find highly misleading and incorrect as far as my experience with writing an internationalized app with php/MySQL: "if your app is multilingual and storing multiple languages within the same tables, you're mostly screwed and should worry about sorting/collating outside of the database". Reciprocal down vote? Wow, that's mature. I'll improve my answer.

Comment: "Reciprocal down vote?" You're not answering OP's question; look no further. I'm in no way claiming you cannot sort in MySQL at all, btw. I do claim from experience that it's impractical (e.g. name a few ORMs that support COLLATE in a proper manner), and that the text field's encoding (note that encoding != collation) is irrelevant when it contains text in multiple languages with inherently different collation rules -- because you'll need to override it anyway. Ergo, `utf8_general_ci` is as good as any.

Comment: My answer's first paragraph clearly answers OP's question "But how does _unicode_ci differ from _danish_ci?". From my experience, sorting for multiple languages with COLLATE is very practical. It can be done directly or via ORM, I've done it with Doctrine.   Clearly encoding != collation but in mysql the first part of the collation does seem to dictate the character set as I've explained and you can read on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-mysql.html